# Access statusbar on form from cplex callback function c#

Tags: c#, .net, callback, cplex

I'm working with an C# .Net application that uses Cplex DLL's for an optimization operation, and during that operation I want to write status progress to a statusbar on the that initiated the operation.

This is the general layout of the specific form;

```
namespace ActResMain
{
    public class FormOptimize : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private callCplex()
        {
            //...
            cplex.Use(new Cplex_ContinuousCallback());
            cplex.Solve()
        }
        public void Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel(String strText)
        {
                statusBarPanel_1.Text = strText;
                statusBar1.Refresh();
        }
        internal class Cplex_ContinuousCallback : Cplex.ContinuousCallback
        {
            FormOptimize formOpt = new FormOptimize();
            public override void Main()
            {
                //From here I want to edit the statusbar at FormOptimize. I can write progress to console without any problems, but cannot reach function "Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel".
                //If I include "FormOptimize formOpt = new FormOptimize" here, i get Visual studio exception on illegal window reference.
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have also tried invoking the Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel function like this:

```
internal class Cplex_ContinuousCallback : Cplex.ContinuousCallback
            {
                FormOptimize formOpt = new FormOptimize();
                public override void Main()
                {
                    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
                    var mpc = fc[1];
                    Type type = mpc.GetType(); 
                    MethodInfo dynMethod = type.GetMethod("Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel");
                    dynMethod.Invoke(mpc, new object[] { String.Format("Running Optimization: {0} iterations ", Niterations)});
                }
            }
```

But then I get an exception from visual studio stating that an object created by one thread cannot be modified from another thread.

Maybe this is something stupid that I have missed, but help is greatly appriciated

EDIT: I edited the code as per Mohammad Dehghans suggestion,

```
public class FormOptimize : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private callCplex()
    {
        cplex.Use(new Cplex_ContinuousCallback(this));
        cplex.Solve()
    }

    internal class Cplex_ContinuousCallback : Cplex.ContinuousCallback
    {
        FormOptimize _formOptimize;
        public Cplex_ContinuousCallback(FormOptimize formOptimize)
        {
            this._formOptimize = formOptimize;
        }

        public override void Main()
        {
            if (Niterations % 10 == 0)
            {
                _formOptimize.Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel(0, String.Format("Running Optimization: {0} iterations ", Niterations), 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel(short panelIndex, String strText, short severity)
    {
        if (statusBar1.InvokeRequired)
            statusBar1.Invoke(new Action<short, string, short>(Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel), panelIndex, strText, severity);
        else
        {
            if (panelIndex == 0)
            {
                //...
                statusBarPanel_0.Text = strText;
            }
            else if (panelIndex == 1)
            {
                //...
                statusBarPanel_1.Text = strText;

            }
            statusBar1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

But by doing that I apparently broke something, as the application just ..stops after statusBar1.Invoke() is called the first time. If I pause the debugger it says that cplex.Solve() is executing, but then nothing more happens.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to pass the instance of your form to the implemented callback class, so when the `Main` method is called, you have access to the exact instance that is being shown on the screen.

Secondly, you need to use [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) method to update the UI controls from anther thread (I've not worked with CPLEX so far, but I guess the callback is invoked from another thread. That's usual).
[Read this for more information.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx)

The complete code could be:

```
public class FormOptimize : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private callCplex()
    {
        //Misc code
        cplex.Use(new Cplex_ContinuousCallback(this)); // <-- passing `this`
        cplex.Solve()
        //Misc code
    }

    public void Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel(String strText)
    {
        if (statusBarPanel_1.InvokeRequired)
            statusBarPanel_1.Invoke(Action<string>(Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel), strText);
        else
        {
            statusBarPanel_1.Text = strText;
            statusBar1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    internal class Cplex_ContinuousCallback : Cplex.ContinuousCallback
    {
        FormOptimize _formOptimize;
        public Cplex_ContinuousCallback(FormOptimize formOptimize)
        {
            this._formOptimize = formOptimize;
        }

        public override void Main()
        {
            //...
            _formOptimize.Update_OptimizeStatusbarPanel(String.Format("Running Optimization: {0} iterations ", Niterations));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it both solved the problem and created another one. Now the application seems to halt on something after calling statusbar1.Invoke I updated my question with my interpretation of your answer. Did implement something incorrect?